# How to search a part of a variable in a table?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to build a query whereby I want to search a part of a variable. Let me explain this:

Example table:

- ID          COLOUR
- 01 red
- 02 blue
- 03 green

I also have a variable $product, which has the value "red socks"
How can I build this query? It should be something like this:

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE colour CONTAINS '$product' " );

But CONTAINS is not a valid argument of course.

Comment: You can use Like Statement in the query where `color` like '%$product%'

Comment: Google MySQL MATCH AGAINST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE '$product' like concat('%', Colour, '%')" );
```

Be careful with $product, you risc SQL injection attacks if you let a user enter it, for example on a website. In a production environment, use bound variables.

Comment: thanks for your advice. This query is not used for user-entering, no worries. 
$product is not a column name, so I think this is wrong

Comment: This isn't wrong, it's the most logical answer. $product is the variable name in your PHP

Comment: No, it's not wrong, it's just unusual. Everyone is used to `where column like 'some string'`. But `where 'some string' like 'column'` works as well, which is used here -- together with wildcards around the column, so `where 'red socks' like '%red%'` is what this expands to, which is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use Like:

```
SELECT Col1
FROM Table
WHERE Col1 LIKE 'PARTOFWORD%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `like` to search words on your queries.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE colour LIKE '%$product%' " );
```

---

Then if you want to search colours by ID use this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE colour='%$idcolour%' " );
```

where `idcolour` is selected on a user control.

Answer (score 1):

You need like clause: `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE colour LIKE '%$product%' " );`

Comment: This will only work the other way round. The value of colour (red) is shorten than the value of $product (red socks)

Answer (score 0):

Use [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) to search using wild-cards (`%`):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE colour LIKE '%ellow%'
```

Comment: This will only work the other way round.
Since the value of colour is shorter than the value of the variable, I don't think this will work:
coulour = red
$product = 'red socks'